# Find limit of recursive complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers, recursion

Sequence is defined as follows:

$$z_0 = 4\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

$$z_{n + 1} = \frac{z_n + |z_{n}|}{2}$$

Task is to find $\lim_{n \to \infty}{z_n}$

I've decomposed the task of finding limit of $z_n$ to finding limits of $x_n$ and $y_n$ (real and imaginary parts of $z_n$). For $y_n$ it's quite obviously decreasing to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

However for $x_n$ it gets complicated. I was able to proof that $lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n}$ exists due to sequence monotonically increasing and being a Cauchy sequence (which is equivalent to being bounded). But I can't find a way to evaluate the limit itself (only numerically with computer, but that doesn't count). Does anybody know how to explicitly find this limit?

Comment: Take the limit as $n \to +\infty$ of your definition $z_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(z_n + |z_n|)$. This gives an equation verified by $\lim z_n$.

Comment: Hint: look at the form of $z_0$. Polar representation works better for this - both $\left|z_n\right|$ and $\arg{z_n}$ behave nicely; you end up with an infinite product to work out (but it's not too bad).

Comment: @Kovomaka if I understood you correctly, solving $lim_{n \to \infty}{z_{n+1}} = lim_{n \to \infty}{z_n}$ doesn't really give anything except $lim_{n \to \infty}{z_{n}} = lim_{n \to \infty}{|z_n|}$, which just means that $z_n$ converges to $x_n$, but I still need to find that $x_n$

Comment: @ChrisLewis Ok, will try that, thought polar representation won't work here

Comment: @SergeyArbuzov Oh you are right, I didn't read your post carefully enough.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Tried it, didn't work out, it just gets ugly after $z_2$. Unless I can't see some algebraic trick...

Comment: @SergeyArbuzov is the limit converging to $\frac{12}{\pi}$?

Comment: @Ercanayan no, at least numerically it converges to approximately $3.3079733725$

Comment: @SergeyArbuzov I've also checked on geogebra and get $\frac{12}{\pi}$: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/bwscuzuk

Comment: @hr3nk Afterall my answer did work.

Comment: @Ercanayan yes, it was correct! somehow I messed up my numerical estimation in standard form, I later used python's built in cmath to properly work with it and got the same answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work out the limit, it's easiest to use a polar representation for $z_n$ (as hinted by the form of $z_0$). Let $z_n = R_n e^{it_n}$, where $R_n$ and $t_n$ are real.

Then
$$z_{n+1}=\frac{R_n e^{it_n}+R_n}{2} = \frac{R_n}{2}\left(1+e^{it_n}\right)$$

Now, using $\cos{t_n}=2\cos^2{\frac{t_n}{2}}$ a couple of times, we can show $\left|1+e^{it_n}\right|=2\cos{\frac{t_n}{2}}$ and $\arg{\left(1+e^{it_n}\right)} =\frac{t_n}{2}$, so
$$R_{n+1}=R_n \cos{\frac{t_n}{2}}$$
and
$$t_{n+1}=\frac{t_n}{2}$$

The argument tends to zero as $n$ tends to $\infty$; so in the limit we're only interested in the value of $R_n$.

We have $R_{n+1}=R_0 \prod_{k=0}^n \cos{\frac{t_0}{2^k}}$. This product is equal to
$$R_0 \frac{\sin{t_0}}{t_0}=\frac{12}{\pi}$$

Comment: Interesting, you have a different result to @abezhiko

Comment: You can check: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NestList%5B%28%23+%2B+abs%28%23%29%29%2F2+%26%2C+4exp%28i+pi%2F6.%29%2C+10%5D

Comment: I love both yours and @Abezhiko solutions! Your seems more convinient in terms of final product convergance, which can be proven with simple trigonometric formula. Thank you very much, was able to learn a lot from both of you

Answer (score 5):

If the sequence $z_{n+1} = f(z_n)$ converges, its limit will be a fixed point of $f(z)$, hence the equation $z = \frac{1}{2}(z+|z|)$ and $z = |z|$, so that we know straighforwardly that $z_\infty$ will be real, but we can't do more from there, that is why we will have to solve the sequence explicitly.

In polar coordinates, i.e. $z_n = r_ne^{i\theta_n}$, we get :
$$
\begin{cases}
   r_{n+1}\cos\theta_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}r_n(1+\cos\theta_n) \\
   r_{n+1}\sin\theta_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}r_n\sin\theta_n
\end{cases}
$$
Dividing the second recurrence relation by the first one leads to
$$
\theta_{n+1} = \mathrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin\theta_n}{1+\cos\theta_n}\right) = \mathrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\mathrm{tan}\frac{\theta_n}{2}\right) = \frac{\theta_n}{2},
$$
and thus $\theta_n = 2^{-n}\theta_0$, with $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{6}$, hence $\theta_\infty = 0$ as found above. Combined with either the identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ or $\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}$, the initial recurrence relations become $r_{n+1} = r_n\cos\theta_{n+1}$, hence
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
r_n 
   &=& \displaystyle
   r_0\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\theta_k \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   r_0\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(2^{-k}\theta_0) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   r_0\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin(2^{k-1}\theta_0)}{2\sin(2^{-k}\theta_0)} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{r_0}{2^n} \frac{\sin(\theta_0)}{\sin(2^{-n}\theta_0)} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   r_0\frac{\mathrm{sinc}(\theta_0)}{\mathrm{sinc}(2^{-n}\theta_0)}
\end{array}
$$
where we used the fact that the last product is telescoping. Since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{sinc}(2^{-n}\theta_0) = \lim_{x\to0} \mathrm{sinc}(x) = 1$, we end up with $r_\infty = r_0\,\mathrm{sinc}(\theta_0) = 4\cdot\frac{\sin(\pi/6)}{\pi/6} = \frac{12}{\pi}$.

Comment: Hm. We get a different result. I've checked numerically and am getting $\frac{12}{\pi}$. I don't think the factor of two is right in your sinc function. Here's a numerical verification: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NestList%5B%28%23+%2B+abs%28%23%29%29%2F2+%26%2C+4exp%28i+pi%2F6.%29%2C+10%5D

Comment: I mis-indexed the product actually, I’ll correct it soon.

Comment: Thank you for your solution too! This problem was out of my league, but it is very interesting. It's a little bit unrelated, but do you know any collections of problems of similar kind, so I can practice? I have read couple of calculus books, but there are little to no tasks on complex sequences, especially recursive? :)

Comment: @hr3nk   I'm not aware of a book dedicated to complex sequences specifically $-$ even it probably exists. However, they are treated in the same as real sequences for the main part, that is why you can refer to books about discrete mathematics dealing with recurrence relations.